# Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4. No operations allowed after connection closed

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mybatis, druid

I have a scheduled task running every 20 minutes which was configured through "@Scheduled(cron = "0 0/20 * * * ?")" based on spring boot. During this task, I need to search some data from mysql and then save them into redis. The following are my configure of database:

```
mybatis.configuration.map-underscore-to-camel-case=true
spring.datasource.type=com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource
#spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.initialSize=1
spring.datasource.minIdle=1
spring.datasource.maxActive=20
spring.datasource.maxWait=60000
spring.datasource.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=60000
spring.datasource.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=300000
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 'x'
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle=true
spring.datasource.testOnBorrow=false
spring.datasource.testOnReturn=false
spring.datasource.poolPreparedStatements=true
spring.datasource.maxPoolPreparedStatementPerConnectionSize=20
spring.datasource.filters=stat,wall,slf4j
spring.datasource.initialize=false
```

The mysql version is v5.7.19. My mysql-connector-java version is 5.1.41. My druid version is 1.0.29. JDK is 18.

My problem is my scheduled task only can execute successfully sometimes. For example, my application runs 24 hours. There must be one or two times failed executing tasks. But I have another scheduled task which runs every 10 minutes, need to connect to the same mysql through the same configuration and it is successful every time.
When the task failed, the log information are:

```
2018-02-14 02:20:00,003 [pool-5-thread-1] INFO  c.x.r.b.r.provider.YourFavoriates Method:executeItemInfoUpdateTaskRun Line:359 - Host IP 10.189.145.64: Scheduled task(executeItemInfoUpdateTask) is begining to save the available skuId information of all storeId from mysql to cache.
2018-02-14 02:20:00,026 [pool-5-thread-1] INFO  o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader Method:loadBeanDefinitions Line:317 - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [org/springframework/jdbc/support/sql-error-codes.xml]
2018-02-14 02:20:00,060 [pool-5-thread-1] INFO  o.s.j.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory Method:<init> Line:127 - SQLErrorCodes loaded: [DB2, Derby, H2, HSQL, Informix, MS-SQL, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Sybase, Hana]
2018-02-14 02:20:00,067 [pool-5-thread-1] WARN  o.s.j.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory Method:getErrorCodes Line:218 - Error while extracting database name - falling back to empty error codes
org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:342)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:366)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory.getErrorCodes(SQLErrorCodesFactory.java:212)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.setDataSource(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:134)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.<init>(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:97)
    at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.initExceptionTranslator(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:87)
    at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:72)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:446)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy86.selectOne(Unknown Source)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectOne(SqlSessionTemplate.java:166)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:82)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:59)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy87.countForQueryAvailableSku(Unknown Source)
    at com.xstore.recommend.biz.recommend.provider.YourFavoriates.getAvailableItems(YourFavoriates.java:68)
    at com.xstore.recommend.biz.recommend.provider.YourFavoriates.executeItemInfoUpdateTaskRun(YourFavoriates.java:360)
    at com.xstore.recommend.biz.recommend.provider.YourFavoriates.executeItemInfoUpdateTask(YourFavoriates.java:467)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor126.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:918)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:897)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:886)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.throwConnectionClosedException(ConnectionImpl.java:1198)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.checkClosed(ConnectionImpl.java:1193)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getMetaData(ConnectionImpl.java:2903)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getMetaData(ConnectionImpl.java:2898)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.invoke(AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.java:70)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:81)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy118.getMetaData(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:331)
    ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 31,199,913 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 31,199,929 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:989)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3746)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2509)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2501)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:1197)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor119.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:138)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy119.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.query(PreparedStatementHandler.java:63)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.query(RoutingStatementHandler.java:79)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.doQuery(SimpleExecutor.java:63)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.queryFromDatabase(BaseExecutor.java:324)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.query(BaseExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:109)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:83)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:148)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:141)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectOne(DefaultSqlSession.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:433)
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: 断开的管道
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3728)
    ... 46 common frames omitted
2018-02-14 02:20:00,069 [pool-5-thread-1] ERROR c.x.r.b.r.provider.YourFavoriates Method:executeItemInfoUpdateTask Line:469 - Exception while executing executeItemInfoUpdateTaskRun.
org.springframework.dao.RecoverableDataAccessException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 31,199,913 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 31,199,929 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
### The error may exist in URL [jar:file:/home/export/App/intelligenceRS.man.7fresh.com/WEB-INF/lib/xstore-intelligence-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/mapper/popMd/PopMdMapper.xml]
### The error may involve defaultParameterMap
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: select count(1) from search_base_data where           isIgnoreSearchVisible = 0 and has_stock = 1 and search_invisible = 1
### Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 31,199,913 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 31,199,929 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
; SQL []; The last packet successfully received from the server was 31,199,913 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 31,199,929 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 31,199,913 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 31,199,929 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.doTranslate(SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.java:98)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:73)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:446)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy86.selectOne(Unknown Source)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectOne(SqlSessionTemplate.java:166)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:82)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:59)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy87.countForQueryAvailableSku(Unknown Source)
    at com.xstore.recommend.biz.recommend.provider.YourFavoriates.getAvailableItems(YourFavoriates.java:68)
    at com.xstore.recommend.biz.recommend.provider.YourFavoriates.executeItemInfoUpdateTaskRun(YourFavoriates.java:360)
    at com.xstore.recommend.biz.recommend.provider.YourFavoriates.executeItemInfoUpdateTask(YourFavoriates.java:467)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor126.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 31,199,913 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 31,199,929 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:989)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3746)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2509)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2501)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:1197)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor119.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:138)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy119.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.query(PreparedStatementHandler.java:63)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.query(RoutingStatementHandler.java:79)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.doQuery(SimpleExecutor.java:63)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.queryFromDatabase(BaseExecutor.java:324)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.query(BaseExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:109)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:83)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:148)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:141)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectOne(DefaultSqlSession.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:433)
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: 断开的管道
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3728)
    ... 46 common frames omitted
```

What is the real reason? I search the answer from the Internet. Many peple said to change the testOnBorrow to true, or extend the mysql connection timeout, etc. These answer cannot meet my problem. So, help me, please. I have been beset by this problem for a week.

Answer (score 1):

It is very important to understand the connection pool that is being used.

The information provided regarding different DB types are kinda insufficient, but here is my initial analysis and some important pointers that would help :

1)If you are using spring data jpa or starter jpa ,you are most probably using tomcat connection pool by default.

Here is some more details (A good read):https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html

Btw, also an easy way to check this is in the logs, you will see org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.* logs.

2) Secondly ,if it is as stated in #1 ,the connection pool properties could be applied via in application.properties :

```
spring.datasource.tomcat.min-idle=1
spring.datasource.tomcat.validation-query= select 1
spring.datasource.tomcat.validation-interval=30000
spring.datasource.tomcat.remove-abandoned-timeout=120
spring.datasource.tomcat.remove-abandoned=true
spring.datasource.tomcat.log-abandoned=true
```

3) Last, but a very important thing to note is the datasource type :

```
spring.datasource.type=com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource
```

Haven't actually tried it ,but i believe the properties you are using in application.properties are being applied to tomcat pool, which am not sure, if it is being even used or not in the application (insufficient info).

Regardless, coming back to the issue at hand, you would have to take a look at the actual Datasource configuration which would "actually" be applied to your tx connection , take a look at the below class for actual properties being used:

https://github.com/alibaba/druid/blob/master/src/main/java/com/alibaba/druid/pool/DruidDataSource.java

also you can give the below test kinda properties a shot :

https://github.com/alibaba/druid/blob/master/druid-spring-boot-starter/src/test/resources/application.properties

```
#Druid 数据源配置，继承spring.datasource.* 配置，相同则覆盖
spring.datasource.druid.initial-size=2
spring.datasource.druid.max-active=30
spring.datasource.druid.min-idle=2
spring.datasource.druid.max-wait=1234
spring.datasource.druid.pool-prepared-statements=true
spring.datasource.druid.max-pool-prepared-statement-per-connection-size=5
#spring.datasource.druid.max-open-prepared-statements= #等价于上面的max-pool-prepared-statement-per-connection-size
spring.datasource.druid.validation-query=select 1
spring.datasource.druid.validation-query-timeout=1
spring.datasource.druid.test-on-borrow=true
spring.datasource.druid.test-on-return=true
```

Hope that helps!!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I specified the connection pool through spring.datasource.type=com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource in the file of application.properties.  But I configured it through  like "spring.datasource.initialSize=1", the prefix of key is spring.datasource, but not spring.datasource.druid. Is this the problem root? I will try later.

Answer (score 0):

The exception was not occurred again after I canceled the redis operation before database connection. I am not sure whether there are any relations between them. It is very strange. There must be some real reason which I don't find out.